# If the range of $log_2\,{x}$ lies between $(-∞, -1)\cup(0,1)$, then how do we find the range of $x$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

If $log_2\,{x}$ lied between $(-2,2)$, then we could just substitute the extreme values in the logarithm, by equating $2$ to $log_2\,{2^2}$ and equating $-2$ to $log_2\,{2^{-2}}$

If via an inequality, we find the range of  $log_2\,{x}$ to be $(-∞, -1)\cup(0,1)$, then how do we find the range of $x$?

Comment: $a<\log_2 x<b \iff 2^a<x<2^b$. For the extreme cases you can use limits (for example, $\lim_ {a\to -\infty} 2^a =0$)